# Angular change route and then call function in that controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

So I have two routes, one of which is a leaflet map. I have a socket.io thing running, giving the map pins, and I have toast notifications on both views when a new pin is added.

When a user clicks on a toast, it *should* zoom to the location of that pin, but I only know how to implement that when I'm already in the map controller.

How do I approach this problem? As I see it, I need to switch routes and call a function in the new controller with an argument, which doesn't seem possible.

My route config, in the main module.

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/chat', {
      templateUrl: 'chat/chat.html',
      controller: 'ChatCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'chat'
    })
    .when('/map', {
      templateUrl: 'map/map.html',
      controller: 'MapCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/map'});
}])
```

Comment: You're basically just calling a route with a specific parameter right?

Comment: @dwbartz I that would work, but I don't see a way to change routes besides `$location.path('/whatever');` or a link on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ng-href to set the url for an anchor inside the toast that the user clicks.

```
<a ng-href="#/map/{{pinId}}" />
```

Then when the user clicks that it will route them to the map path.  In the controller you should inject **$routeParams** to check whether a param is set and if so to them zoom the user to that pin.

Comment: Yep I was being dumb. Thanks!

Comment: @mtfurlan Happy to help